# Hay algún método para ordernar views dento de un relative layout?

Tags: android

Quisiera saber si existe alguna función para poder sobreponer un TextView que se encuentra debajo de otro dentro de un relative layout programaticamente? O la unica manera sería removerlo y volviendolo a agregar con addView()? Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podes hacerlo de dos formas, en ves de eliminarlo y añadirlo podrias cambiarle la visibilidad

```
TuComponente.Visivility = View.VISIBLE -|- View.GONE; (depende de cual necesites)
```

La otra forma seria traer al frente tu componente

```
TuComponente.bringToFront()
```

Espero que te sirva

Comment: LcsGrz q no te encuentre en la calle porq sino te beso.... Bien amigo si me sirve ese método. Ahora estoy trabajando en un proyecto complejo. Pero no conocía ese método. Iba remover y volver a añadir un AppBarLayout completo con sus Tabs y todo. Oye muchas gracias hermano.

Comment: AY :$ jaja, me alegro que te haya funcionado, no olvides marcar como respuesta mi pregunta si realmente funciono ,y puntuarla!

Comment: Como se hace? No puedo. Dice q no tengo reputación suficiente. :(

Comment: Espera... Ya lo encontré. Es el check no?. Q tonto.

Comment: Si es el check! , gracias por aportar a la comunidad, cualquier duda me podes buscar por redes sociales con el mismo nombre :D saludos!